# Why this [haskell] compilation error?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

```
module Main

alicebob :: String -> String
alicebob "alice" = "Hi alice"
alicebob "bob" = "Hi bob"
alicebob _ = "Hi person whose name is neither alice nor bob."

greet :: IO ()
greet = do
      putStrLn "hi. whats your name?"
      name <- getLine
      putStrLn (alicebob name)
```

Simple programming exercise to get some user input, and reply. Just starting to learn haskell so please excuse the simple question. Getting an error on line `alicebob :: 
String -> String`. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: For future reference, if you're posting on here about a compiler error, you should copy/paste the error into your post.  While this one was simply that you missed the `where` at the end of `module Main` as @DanielFischer pointed out, as you advance in the language the errors you'll see will be more difficult to ascertain at a glance.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is on that line?  [In ideone, your code](http://ideone.com/N3Mbye) actually generates "parse error on input `module'".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module header must contain a `where`,

```
module Main where
--          ^^^^^
```

The compiler expects to find the `where` (possibly preceded by an export list) and when it finds `alicebob` instead, it throws an error.